# How does ARC work in the following code snippet in ios?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Let's say I have a method that returns an object pointer

```
-(MyObj *) returnMyObj {
   MyObj *obj = [MyObj alloc] init];
   return obj;
}
```

If I call this function without assigning the pointer like this

**Scenario 1**

```
[self returnMyObj];
```

and if I call this function with assignment to a pointer like this

**Scenario 2**

```
MyObj* obj = [self returnMyObj];
```

Compiler can release the object at the end of the **returnMyObj** method call in the Scenario 1 but it cant do the same in Scenario 2.How does ARC decide if it needs to retain the created object at the end of method invocation or not in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer may absolutely release the object in scenario 2 at the end of the statement if `obj` is not referenced later in the block.

The whole point is that the optimizer can see when the pointer is referenced, and may release it as soon as the last reference is completed. `obj` does not have precise lifetime semantics, so it only extends the life of the object until the last time `obj` is referenced, not when `obj` goes out of scope.

In scenario 1, the reference is not assigned to any variable, so it clearly has no later references, and may be immediately released. That said, it may not immediately release the object, since `returnMyObj` does not transfer ownership to the caller (due to its name). So the object may not actually be released until the autorelease pool drains.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by draining of autorelease pool here ? Does ARC insert some on its own and then drain them.

Comment: ARC will always insert some kind of autorelease before the `return obj` line. Depending on the situation, the optimizer may remove it, and it can often be eliminated at runtime when autorelease+retain happens.

Comment: This is getting really into the weeds of ARC optimizations, and typically isn't important for day-to-day work. If you want to dig into this kind of stuff, you want to read the docs. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html and Mike Ash's excellent introduction to the guts. https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html and also http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/

Answer (score 2):

Here is what the ARC [article](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) in the documentation has to say:

> To make sure that instances don’t disappear while they are still needed, ARC tracks how many properties, constants, and variables are currently referring to each class instance. ARC will not deallocate an instance as long as at least one active reference to that instance still exists.
>
> To make this possible, whenever you assign a class instance to a property, constant, or variable, that property, constant, or variable makes a strong reference to the instance. The reference is called a “strong” reference because it keeps a firm hold on that instance, and does not allow it to be deallocated for as long as that strong reference remains.

ARC decides which objects will be kept in memory and which will be deallocated by counting the strong references to the objects.

In your second scenario you are creating a strong reference to the `MyObj` instance and ARC will not deallocate it while the object is in use. In this case it will be deallocated when the method that uses this object finishes.

Comment: I would drop the phrase "which increases the retain count with 1" here. It generally would never do that literally for an automatic variable like this (retain counts are internal details maintained at runtime). But it does create a "reference" that the compiler and optimizer track at compile time.